# fontspec, Fontforge: How to set a layer of a character in a document

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, fontforge

I create a font [`myfont.ttf`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL_EXXqKUz677jWVSsHrGa8k5FrIvN_R/view?usp=sharing) in *FontForge*. In that I built a new layer, which gets the name 'Back 3' (don't know why), and set in the layers `Fore - Back - Back 3` a rectangle, a circle and a star 
(BTW: I do not know, whether this is the right way).

When I call up the chacter in my document, see MWE, I get the 'rectangle'.

So my question is:
Is there any way to put only one of these other layers in the document, for example only the 'star'? 
I think about something like `\symbol[layer=3]{65}`. 
Is this possible?

[**myfont.ttf and tex-file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL_EXXqKUz677jWVSsHrGa8k5FrIvN_R/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\myfont}[Scale=1]{myfont.ttf}
\begin{document}
Test: \Huge\myfont\symbol{65}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to fontforge's documentation: "... only the topmost foreground layer will be rendered into your final font." So only one font will actually become part of your font. (You can enable adding all layers to the custom `PfEd` table, but they would have to be parsed separately and converted into actual graphics.